# Why isn't my header going back to original position?

Tags: jquery, css

Im having an issue with my sticky header. [see here](https://www.hbpsystems.co.uk), as you scroll 80 pixels from the top the header gets the class sticky-header added and when you scroll back up it removes the class and go back to original position

It seems to be working altho the client has come back and said that its not working.

As for some reason when scroll down then back up it seems to ignore the top header.

[image]

Only js code I have.

```
$(window).resize(addremoveclass());
$(window).scroll(addremoveclass());

function addremoveclass() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 70) { // this refers to window
            console.log("You've scrolled 80 pixels.");
            $('#pageTemplate').addClass('stickypadding');
            $('header#header.header-sticky-mobile').css('top', '0px');
            $('header#header').addClass('header-sticky-mobile');
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 69){
            $('#pageTemplate').removeClass('stickypadding');
            $('header#header').removeClass('header-sticky-mobile');
            $('header#header.header-sticky-mobile').css('top', '80px');
        }
    } else {
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 70) { // this refers to window
            console.log("You've scrolled 80 pixels.");
            $('#pageTemplate').addClass('stickypadding');
            $('header#header.header-sticky-mobile').css('top', '0px');
            $('header#header').addClass('header-sticky-mobile');
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 69){
            $('#pageTemplate').removeClass('stickypadding');
            $('header#header').removeClass('header-sticky-mobile');
            $('header#header.header-sticky-mobile').css('top', '80px');
        }

    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know, but there was no option for a sticky header in the wordpress theme so had to build it in which was rather annoying.

Comment: Josh is totally right use CSS here. You are writing a lot for less, jQuery is Do More And Write Less. SYA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened when you refresh in the middle of the page.

Add `$(this).scrollTop(0);` to your document ready as first thing:

like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);

    //.....

});
```